# R parsing html to get a value

Tags: html, r, parsing

I would like to get the flood risk associated with any given post code, and would like to use [this website](http://maps.environment-agency.gov.uk/wiyby/wiybyController?x=357683.0&y=355134.0&scale=1&layerGroups=default&ep=map&textonly=off&lang=_e&topic=floodmap) to do so. And then by clicking on text-only.

I would like to query this website by giving it a postcode and getting a TRUE or FALSE response, based on the if the response comes back as Yes or No.

Below is the code I have written so far to try and produce this...

but my htmlresp_content object has a class of `"HTMLInternalDocument" "HTMLInternalDocument" "XMLInternalDocument"  "XMLAbstractDocument"` which I do not know how to parse/extract the relevant information from....

```
 postcode_flood_risk <- function(PC){

    require(httr)

    htmlresp <- GET(paste0('http://maps.environment-agency.gov.uk/wiyby/wiybyController?value=',
                           gsub(' ','+',PC),
                           '&submit.x=-1&submit.y=11&submit=Search%09&lang=_e&ep=summary&topic=floodmap&layerGroups=default&scale=9&textonly=off'))

    htmlresp_content <- content(htmlresp)

    # code to extract the 'Yes' or 'No' from htmlresp_content
    # for now automatically choose yes
    flood_risk <- 'Yes'

    if(flood_risk=='Yes'){
      TRUE
    } else {
      FALSE
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you give us a working url? I need a "PC", to use your GET statement to see what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in some xpath to get the response

```
postcode_flood_risk <- function(PC){
    require(httr)
    htmlresp <- GET(paste0('http://maps.environment-agency.gov.uk/wiyby/wiybyController?value=',
                           gsub(' ','+',PC),
                           '&submit.x=-1&submit.y=11&submit=Search%09&lang=_e&ep=summary&topic=floodmap&layerGroups=default&scale=9&textonly=off'))

    htmlresp_content <- content(htmlresp)

    # extract the 'Yes'
    out <- htmlresp_content["//table[2]//td[2]//text()"]
    flood_risk <- gsub("\\t|\\r|\\n", "", xmlValue(out[[1]]))

    if(!is.na(flood_risk) && flood_risk=='Yes'){
        TRUE
    } else {
        FALSE
    }
}

postcode_flood_risk("FY6 0AA")
# TRUE
postcode_flood_risk("FY6 0A9")
# FALSE
```

Comment: In the spirit of teach a man how to fish...vs giving him a fish...can you show me how you knew to add the two lines you added...i.e. `out <- htmlresp_content["//table[2]//td[2]//text()"];
    flood_risk <- gsub("\\t|\\r|\\n", "", xmlValue(out[[1]]))`

Comment: Sorry if I am being slow, but how exactly did you 'look at the HTML response and see what tags I could use'?